# Should the kernel pass data from a tap interface to an application listening on INADDR_ANY?

Tags: networking

I have an application that creates, listens on and writes to a tap interface.  The software will `read(tun_fd,...)` and perform some action on that data, and it will return data to the system as UDP packets via `write(tun_fd,...)`.

I assign an IP to the interface, `10.10.10.10\24` so that a socket application can bind to it and so that the kernel will pass any packets for the virtual subnet to the tap interface.

The software generate frames with IP/UDP packets with the destination IP being that assigned to the interface, and a source IP existing in the same subnet. The source and dest mac address match that of the tap device.  Those frames are written back to the kernel with `write(tun_fd,...)`.

If I open said tap interface in wireshark I will see my frames/packets as I expect to, properly formatted, expected ports, expected macs and IPs.  But if I try to read those packets with `netcat -lvu 0.0.0.0 ${MY_UDP_PORT}` I don't see anything.

Is this expected behavior?

**Update 1**

`INADDR_ANY` is a red herring.  I have the problem even when explicitly binding to an interface / port as in this pseudo code:

```
#> # make_tap_gen is a fake program that creates a tap interface and pushes UDP packets to 10.10.10.10@1234
#> ./make_tap_gen tun0
#> ip addr add dev tun0 10.10.10.10/24
#> netcat -lvu 10.10.10.10 1234
```

**Update 2**

I modified my code to be able to switch to a tun as opposed to a tap and I experience the same issue (well formatted packets in Wireshark but no data in socket applications).

**Update 3**

In the [kernel documentation for tuntap](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) it says

> Let's say that you configured IPv6 on the tap0, then whenever
> the kernel sends an IPv6 packet to tap0, it is passed to the application
> (VTun for example). The application encrypts, compresses and sends it to
> the other side over TCP or UDP. The application on the other side decompresses
> and decrypts the data received and writes the packet to the TAP device,
> the kernel handles the packet like it came from real physical device.

This implies to me that a `write(tun_fd,...)` where the packet was properly formatted and destined for an IP assigned to some interface on the system should be received by any application listening to `0.0.0.0:${MY_UDP_PORT}`

Comment: Same behavior when using a TUN or a TAP interface.

Comment: A TAP interface is for layer-2 frames, not layer-3 IP packets, and a TUN interface is one end of a tunnel to which the interface will send packets. It sounds like you really want just a virtual interface for packets destined to your same host, and those are loopback addresses. You have over 16 million of those in the `127.0.0.0/8` IPv4 loopback block, but only one for IPv6 `::1`.

Comment: I will admit that TUN/TAP devices are new to me, but I am a bit comfortable with low level networking in general.  When I switch between TAP and TUN I change the type of packet I am generating (layer 2 vs layer 3), and in the case of the TAP interface I'll respond to ARPs for nodes that I consider on my 'network'.  The actual purpose of the application to hide a proprietary interface containing N nodes behind this one tap device that I want to look like a connection to the 10.10.10.0/24 subnet.  Does that sound like a proper application of a TUN/TAP device?

Comment: "_I change the type of packet I am generating (layer 2 vs layer 3)_" Layer-2 is frames, and layer-3 is packets. So a TAP interface must be bridged because it is layer-2 (MAC addressing), while a TUN interface is routed (IP addressing). Netcat will need something like loopback addressing to see what you want because binding to 0.0.0.0 is looking for packets destined to your host, not packets being sent from your host. Use a loopback address to test this, and netcat should see the packets.

Comment: My understanding was that if I created a tap device in my program (fd = fopen(...)) and then put data into it with write(fd), that the OS would receive that frame just like it arrived over a wire plugged into an Ethernet adapter.  And if that was true then assigning an address to that interface would be the same as assigning one to an Ethernet interface. So if a frame arrived with a destination address (mac and IP) matching the assigned IP that the packet should be delivered to the anyone listening on that IP/port. Am I way off here?

Comment: That is a virtual outbound interface that bridges layer-2 frames. Basically, the same thing as a mirror interface on a switch. A TUN is a virtual outbound interface that sends to a corresponding TUN on a different host, basically a pseudowire between directly-connected virtual interfaces.

Comment: On the other end of the 'proprietary interface' I mentioned is another instance of this software. The 'propriety interface' can actually have many nodes though, almost like a wireless network. I want all those nodes to seem like they're all plugged into each other.   What's a better method?

Comment: Right, but it is an outbound interface from the host perspective. The other end, on the same host, would be an inbound interface from the host perspective. Also, netcat is binding to all layer-3 interfaces, but the TAP interfaces are layer-2 interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, data written into the tuntap device via `write(tun_fd...)` should get passed to the kernel protocol stack and distributed to listening sockets with matching packet information just like the frame had arrived over a wire attached to a physical ethernet device.

It requires that the packets be properly formed (IP checksum is good, UDP checksum is good or 0).  It requires that the kernel know how to handle the packet (is there an interface on the system with a matching destination IP?).  If it's a tap device it may also require that your application is properly ARP'ing (although this might not be necessary for a 'received' packet from the perspective of a socket application listening to an address assigned to the tap device).

In my case the problem was silly.  While I had turned on UDP checksum verification in wireshark I forgot to turn on IP header verification.  An extra byteswap was breaking that checksum.  After fixing that I was immediately able to see packets written into the TAP device in a socket application listening on the address assigned to that interface.